# Connection Timeout - Get Request

Tags: google-maps, connection

I created a web page that finds the latitude and longitude of an address.  It had worked with no issues for weeks, until yesterday, when I started getting a "Connection Timeout" error when using the API script.

I tried the same script on a different server, and it works with no problems.

I am trying to "get" an HTTP request with the sample URL

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=500+Main+Street,+Carmel,IN&sensor=false

When I plug this URL into a browser, it works fine.  I just can't use the HTTP Get request any more.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are probably over the request limit (cf. https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#usagelimits). Try registering a an API key.

Comment: Read the question, it says the user gets a timeout, so it is not because of the apikey.

Comment: I'm down voting the reply because OP specifically mentioned he tried the same script on different server and it worked. So, clearly it's not API key issue.

Comment: @KMC Different server = different IP = different rate limit. For the API, two different servers are two entities, each with their own limit. So its perfectly possible for the OP to hit the rate limit on one server, but not on another,

Comment: @Polygnome OP is getting time out error. I don't think that's anything to do with rate limit.